# How to compute the n-th floating point from 0 in python

Tags: python, floating-point

We know floating points are not distributed evenly. I  want to calculate the n-th floating point from 0 in `Python`. Is there an efficient way to do that?

Let nth_fp be the function. It takes an integer and outputs a floating-point number. The following properties are necessary:

```
1. nth_fp(0) should be 0

2. nth_fp(n)>0 if n>0 

3. nth_fp(n)<0 if n<0

4.nth_fp(m)>nth_fp(n) if m>n
```

Comment: How do you want to handle `-0.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people who laid out the format of [IEEE 64-bit doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) were very clever. They ensured that the next higher representable floating point value is a simple integer increment up from the previous one, with `0.0` being a bit pattern of all zeros. Thus for a positive number `n` you can simply convert the bit pattern to floating point directly.

```
import struct

def nth_fp(n):
    if n < 0:
        sign_bit = 0x8000000000000000
        n = -n
    else:
        sign_bit = 0
    if n >= 0x7ff0000000000000:
        raise ValueError('out of range')
    bit_pattern = struct.pack('Q', n | sign_bit)
    return struct.unpack('d', bit_pattern)[0]
```

As you can see, negative numbers only require the addition of a single bit to the overall pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking about the generality of your code. Do you think it can be extensible to n-th floating point from 'x', which is a parameter of the nth_fp?

Comment: @zell trivially. Just convert the floating point bit pattern to an integer and mask off the sign bit, then add your `n` to the resulting number and run it through the above code.