# Get the n-th double number from a given double in python

Tags: python, floating-point

This question is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713612/how-to-compute-the-n-th-floating-point-from-0-in-python) but I do not see how to extend the answer to that question in an easy way.

Here, I  want to calculate the n-th `double` from a given `double` in `Python`.
The function takes an integer `n`, a double `x`,  and outputs a `double` that is the `n-th` after `x` (or before, if `n` is negative).  Is there an efficient way to do it?

Concretely,  Let nth_fp_after be the function, then nth_fp_after(x,n) should equal to n times the application of nextafter (in C) to x; nth_fp_after(x,0) should be 'x', etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, can you post it? Also, can you give an example of what an input and output would be for a given double and a given n, for clarity sake.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer of the question you pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713612/how-to-compute-the-n-th-floating-point-from-0-in-python) is exactly the answer to your question. The answer solved the problem for for 64 bits float that are the python equivalent of C double.

---

Well, if you add the following

`struct.unpack('!i',struct.pack('!f',x))[0]`

to `n` and use it to call the function of the other answer, you should get it.

---

The full solution by modifying will look like:

```
import struct

def nth_fp(n, x=0.0):
    if(x>=0):
        m = n + struct.unpack('!Q',struct.pack('!d',x))[0]
    else:
        m = n - struct.unpack('!Q',struct.pack('!d',abs(x) ))[0]
    if m < 0:
        sign_bit = 0x8000000000000000
        m = -m
    else:
        sign_bit = 0
    if m >= 0x7ff0000000000000:
        raise ValueError('out of range')
    bit_pattern = struct.pack('Q', m | sign_bit)
    return struct.unpack('d', bit_pattern)[0]
```

I added a default value to the second parameter so that you can used it in both cases, with or without offset `x`.

Comment: i don't think so. That one calculates the double from 0 only, and I do not see an easy way to extend it.

Comment: @zell, the solution is not put there in exact word, I just extract the remaining part that you did not get from the comments and put it in python form. See the edit

Comment: There seems to be a bug somewhere in your code. Running "print nth_fp(0,x=2.5)" should give 2.5 but yours outputs  5.31535078499e-315

Comment: @zell, the bug is to be expected, I did not think about that. There are actually two bugs. We are supposed to mask the sign bit before adding to `n`. The second problem is that it will work only for tiny x. I will think again when I have few minutes.

Comment: @zell, I just corrected the code. This should do the job.

Comment: @zell, did this help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help please let me know so that I can delete it to save people from wasting their time looking at it.